# Python3のpipがインストール済みのKali Linuxに、Python2のpip2をインストールする方法

Tags: python, pip

Kali Linux 2020.2を使用しています。
現在Python 3.8.6と、pip 20.1.1がインストールされています。
pipは `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip` にインストールされており、Python3のために使用されています。

別途、Python 2.7.18がインストールされており、Python2のためにpip2をインストールしたいのですが、インストール方法が分かりません。
どなたかpip2のインストール方法をご教授いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: これらの記事あたりでしょうか。[New Kali build cannot install pip for python2.7 - Kali Linux ...](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?48570-New-Kali-build-cannot-install-pip-for-python2-7), [Unable to install Requests module in python2.7 (Kali linux) as it keeps appearing in python3 library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64376726/9014308), [Not able to install python-pip in kali linux 2019.3 vbox amd 64 with apt-get install python-pip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61268756/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。

Comment: 情報共有として、推測でも良いので原因・状況とか、それから具体的な対処方法・手順とかを自己回答してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

```
# curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
# python get-pip.py
```

で解決しました。